# Linux: search and remove in file, new line when it is between two lines of digits

Tags: file, text, line, solaris, digits

I have a big text file that has this format:

> 80708730272
>
> 598305807640 45097682220
>
> 598305807660 87992655320
>
> 598305807890
>
> 598305808720
>
> 598305809030
>
> 598305809280
>
> 598305809620 564999067
>
> 598305809980
>
> 33723830870

As you can see there is a row of digits and then in some occasions there is a second row.
In the text file (on solaris) the second row is under the first one.
I don't know why they are here side by side.
I want to put a coma whenever there is a number in the second row.

> 598305809620
>   564999067

make it like:

> 598305809620, 564999067

And if I could put also a semicolon ';' at the end of each line it would be perfect.
Could you please help?
What could I use and basically how could I do that?

Comment: I can't seem to find the FS for the file.
I put in awk every combination for FS and Still it does not separate it as it should.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct was `sed` rather than `awk`. They are both excellent tools to have.
I couldn't find an easy way to do it all in a single regex ("regular expression"), though. No doubt someone else will.
`sed -i.bak -r "s/([0-9]+)(\s+[0-9]+)/\1,\2/g" filename.txt`
`sed -i -r "s/[0-9]+$/&;/g" filename.txt.bak`
The first line takes care of the lines with two groups of digits, writing it out to a new file with an extra '.bak' file extension, just to be paranoid (aka 'good practice') and not risk overwriting your original file if you made a mistake.
The second line appends the semi-colon to all lines that contain at least one digit - so, skipping blank lines, for example. It overwrites the .bak file in place.
Once you have verified that the result is satisfactory, replace your original file with this one.

Let me know if you want a detailed explanation of exactly what's going on here.

Comment: I made a huge mistake saying that the OS is Centos.
it is actually Solaris. :S
And -i and -r on sed are not recognized. :(

Comment: Okay, you can get the -i functionality by means of output redirection.<br/>
And the -r functionality by means of escaping the parentheses and hacking in the '+' quantifier.<br/>

Putting it all together we have:<br/>
`sed "s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\(\s\s*[0-9][0-9]*\)/\1,\2/g" filename.txt > filename.bak` <br/>
`sed "s/[0-9][0-9]*$/&;/g" filename.bak > filename.bak2`<br/>
Then check that filename.bak2 looks good, replace filename.txt with it, and delete filename.bak.

My goodness, that is some ugly code.<br/>
I hope someone else can suggest something better.<br/>

Comment: @user2457193 Your question has been edited (CentOS has been replaced by Solaris).

Comment: @user2457193 Hey any time you make a mistake you can click on the 'edit' link below your question (or answer) to make a change. [See the help section for details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Edward, I already solved this by appending ',' and ';' directly to the result on the query.
But I will try your 'monster' just to verify.
And I will let you know about the results!

Thanks all for the time and effort you spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, awk is your friend. Give this a whirl:

```
awk '{if (NF==2) printf "%s, %s;\n\n", $1, $2; else if (NF==1) printf "%s;\n\n", $1}' big_text.txt | cat > txt_file.txt
```

This should result in the following output:

```
80708730272;

598305807640, 45097682220;

598305807660, 87992655320;

598305807890;

598305808720;

598305809030;

598305809280;

598305809620, 564999067;

598305809980;

33723830870;
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: This partially work.
It actually puts ';' on every line.
I think there is something wrong with the space between the two numbers.
Is there a way to determine what is it?
Is it a 'space' is it a '\n' or '\r' or something else maybe?
Because I tried putting as FS all of them and awk was giving me alwas the same wrong result.

Comment: Well it does not put the ',' there where it suppose to be a comma.
Instead it puts the ';'.

Comment: so a line with 2 numbers appears like this: `8789797; 897987;`?

Comment: No it puts every number to a new line and puts a ';'
like this:

8789797;
897987;
It should be in a new line here but it automatically puts it to the same line! :(

Im also 'playing' with awk, with FS and NF but no luck so far! :'(